# Remove CSS on successful submission of a form using Reactive Form Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to remove below CSS from elements on successful submission of a form. I am currently using Reactive Form in Angular and I have used the below CSS to show **red left border along with bold Font** if value is invalid

```
.form-control.ng-dirty:not(form) {
font-weight: bolder;
border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /*green*/
}

.form-control.ng-invalid:not(form) {
border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

When I click save, I want to remove the css (that I applied to show the user that the current value will be updating by changing the font to bolder and left border to green). I am a little bit struggling with this. I tried using temp variable but that doesn't work. Tried passing the **$event** variable from the **onSubmit** but that also not helping

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="formEquipments" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formEquipments, $event)">
    <table class="tableInfo">
        <thead *ngIf="parameterModels?.length > 0">
            <tr>
                <th style="padding-left:30px" *ngFor="let paramType of solverParameterHeader; let i = index">
                    <div class="tableheaders">
                        {{paramType}}
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <ng-container formArrayName="equipmentArray"
                          *ngFor="let paramTypes of formEquipments.get('equipmentArray')['controls']; let i = index">
                <tr [formGroupName]="i">                        
                    <td formArrayName="entityAttributeInfo" *ngFor="let item of paramTypes.controls.entityAttributeInfo.controls; let ii = index;">
                        <div [formGroupName]="ii" class="tabledataEquipmentNameInfo">
                            <input #varData formControlName="value" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**typescript**

```
async onSubmit(formGroup, target) {
    //remove the css after successful submission of the form. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after playing with the $event, I finally found the solution. Below is what I used:

```
@ViewChild('data') data: ElementRef;
divElement: HTMLElement;
```

then on the submit event:

```
async onSubmit(formGroup, target) {
    this.divElement = this.data.nativeElement;
    this.divElement.classList.remove("ng-dirty");
}
```